# How to add default methods to Guice interface

Tags: java, java-8, guice

I've got the following interface:

```
public interface FooFactory {
    Foo create();

    default Foo createWithData(Data data){
        Foo foo = create();
        foo.addData(data);
        return foo;
    }
}
```

I'm installing it as follows:

```
install(new FactoryModuleBuilder().build(FooFactory.class));
```

However, the problem is that **Guice overwrites my default method with its own factory method**.  The Foo I get back is the same Foo from `create()` (no data has been set).  The default method never gets called.

Now, this is simply a convenience method, but is it possible for me to tell Guice not to overwrite my function?

Comment: what are you doing in `FactoryModuleBuilder`? my default methods is not overwrite by guice.

Comment: `FactoryModuleBuilder` is a class provided by google.  I'm doing nothing besides installing the interface

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the `guice-assistedinject` module has a bug for skipping the java-8 default method at line [L252](https://github.com/google/guice/blob/master/extensions/assistedinject/src/com/google/inject/assistedinject/FactoryProvider2.java#L252). and I found there is no tests to [testing](https://github.com/google/guice/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=path%3Aextensions%2Fassistedinject%2Ftest%2Fcom%2Fgoogle%2Finject%2Fassistedinject+default&type=) this feature.

a default method is neither a `bridge` method nor a `synthetic` method at all in java complier. However, its comments says that will *skips the default methods*. and the code should be as:

```
if (isDefault(method)){
  ...
}
```

you need to write your own `Provider` instead.

Comment: I don't think that's a bug, more like working-as-intended.  The comment is "Skip default methods that java8 may have created," not "skip default methods that the developer created."

Comment: @TavianBarnes sir, what are you saying? a feature just for compiler not for human? I think it is meaningless since the condition is always `false`. and the default methods is created by developer.

Comment: @TavianBarnes  I'm happy I'm found this bug that NathanMerrill has been reported this bug into [issues](https://github.com/google/guice/issues/1104).

Comment: Some default methods *are* added by the compiler; I believe return type covariance is the main reason.  Have a look at https://github.com/google/guice/issues/904

Comment: @TavianBarnes sir, thanks very much for your feedback. I'll reading it immediately.

Comment: looks like there has been an attempt to fix it
https://github.com/google/guice/pull/1347
and (as a googler) I'm trying to push it again, but they are afraid of people implementing default methods literally as fallback over the generated one. .. don't ask I don't understand either.